# Error with matrix indices in heat flow simulation

Tags: matlab, matrix

When I run this code that I've written to simulate a heat flow model in MATLAB i get an error that says 'Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.' I think this is probably something to do with my linspace command generating a different type of variable not integers and so it's not working properly but I'm not sure how to amend my script to correct for this.

```
Cp = 400;
p = 8960;
k = 400;
a = k/(p*Cp); 
dt = 0.01;
dx = sqrt(5*a*dt); %% 5 as 1/5 is smaller than 1/4 for stability

T = zeros(20000,10000);

for x = linspace(1,10000,10000);
    T(x,:) = 1000; 
end

for x = linspace(10001,20000,10000);     
    T(x,:) = 25;
end

for  t = linspace(1,10000,10000); 
    for x = linspace(1,20000,20000);
         T(x,t+1) = T(x,t)+a*dt*((T(x-1,t)-2*T(x,t)+ T(x+1,t))/(dx*dx)); 
    end  
end
```

Comment: Besides the indexing error, you use temperatures that are not calculated yet -- i.e. `T(x+1, t)` -- to calculate future temperatures -- i.e. `T(x, t+1)`. This is because your integration order is the other way around. But I guess you noticed this already. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that blows up is:

```
T(x,t+1) = T(x,t)+a*dt*((T(x-1,t)-2*T(x,t)+ T(x+1,t))/(dx*dx));
```

Specifically `T(x-1,t)` triggers the error because `x` starts as 1, hence x - 1 = 0 and 0 is not a valid index.

On a more general Matlab coding note, I would write `x = 1:10000` instead of `x = linspace(1,10000,10000)`, but this is not causing the error. Note that I'm only addressing the Matlab error message. I have no idea whether your overall code works.

Comment: so if i run the last loop for x 2:19999 and t 1:9999 then it should work?

Comment: @goods From a not triggering an indexing error perspective, yes!